# How to do basic semantic search using ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, full-text-search, spacy

I want to implement basic semantic search in my product search service which uses ElasticSearch.

I am fairly new to ML and NLP and implementing a full contextual search using models trained on search analytics will take a significant time.

I am thinking to solve few basic use cases first like - **"yellow shirt"** or **"green jacket"** where in yellow/green are essentially a color filter which I can apply on the keywords shirt/jacket.

How can I implement this kind of query parsing? I know **querqy** is one tool.
Should I be doing something with **spaCy**?

How about this silly logic:

1. Query ElasticSearch with "yellow jacket"
2. Search the tokens (yellow and jacket) in the facets/aggs, if they match then apply that facet as a filter and send a search query to ES again.

So basically "yellow" will be found in the "color" facet and I will apply the `color=yellow` filter.

The downside of this approach is that I'll have to send two queries to ES (two n/w calls) and also, I think that pagination will go hay-wired.

Please suggest me good ways to approach this problem based on your experience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The basic way semantic search works is you get a vector representation of a document (query) and find similar documents (= documents close in vector space). You do not need to pay attention to individual words. You should read about using the vector search feature in ElasticSearch. https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch

Comment: You can use spaCy to get document vectors, but if that's all your using it for other tools would also work fine.

Comment: @polm23 - Thanks. But as I mentioned, implementing a fully fledged NLP solution is a long way to go. What do you think about that custom logic which I mentioned?

Comment: Doing a custom faceted search is complicated. Parsing your query and then making it semantic somehow is complicated. Calculating a vector representation for the query as a whole is very, very easy - it may not do exactly what you want, but it's easy to try. So I would suggest you learn the basics of that before thinking about more variations like the above, which sound more complicated to me.

Comment: It may be helpful to first consider what user experience you want. Do you offer refinement suggestions that can be clicked by users or do you just make the adjustments automatically? How transparent do you want these automated query adjustments to be? Show facets? What if the user disagrees - how do they fix it? e.g. there are several music artists on Spotify called Yellow Jackets. Best to figure out what UX you want before considering the how.